# Attaching Play's 2.2 source code to the application

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

With Play 2.1.3 I could attach Play's source code using `$ play eclipse with-source=true`. But now, after migrating to Play 2.2.1, when I try to run that command I get the error below.

```
$ play eclipse with-source=true
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Play\dcid\project
[info] Set current project to dcid (in build file:/C:/Play/dcid/)
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: with-source
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: with-source (similar: watch-sources, watchSources, sources)
[error] with-source=true
[error]            ^
```

Was the command's syntax updated? How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should work if you run the command inside `play`, like this:

```
play
eclipse with-source=true
```

But you don't need to; if you still want to run the command outside play:

```
play "eclipse with-source=true"
```